# How can I disable all command line access?

Tags: command-line, tty

I make computers for a not-for-profit organisation.

I don't want anyone to plug a keyboard / mouse / screen into it and be able to do anything on it.

So there is a locked screen at launch, but you can still access TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

How can I disable all TTY command lines, or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> shortcuts? (so <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> ... <kbd>F6</kbd>)